# Italicize a text containing *

Tags: support, markdown

I was writting a post mentioning `*` in SQL `SELECT` query when I noticed that I can't make it *Italic* as the editor confused using `*` with an Italic symbol.

How can I make this text italic:

```
write column names instead of *
```

I tried surrounding it with two `*`. This is the result

```
*write column names instead of **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I have to use HTML `<i>` tag like:

```
<i>write column names instead of *</i>
```

It will produce this result:

*write column names instead of **

Answer (score 10):

The markdown way to do this would be to escape the `*` with a `\`.

```
*write column names instead of \**
```

Output:

> *write column names instead of **

Comment: Cool. This is a nice one as well

Comment: It's worth noting that this technique can be useful in non-italicized contexts too, for example if I want to add an asterisk here\* and here\* without them being interpreted as an instruction to italicize the text in between them.